# Ruby on Rails and IOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails

Can someone recommend a road map or step by step guide in how to learn Ruby on Rails and IOS at the same time. I am interested in Web as well in Mobile technology.

Which one should I learn first then second etc..

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Code School](http://codeschool.com) is a great resource for both Rails and the iOS platform. It has tutorials for people who have never even touched ruby as a language before. It is where I started and it is a great and relatively cheap option. If you haven't already, look at [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) as well as [Semantic-UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) and [Zurb's Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) for great examples of mobile friendly designs.